# PostgreSQL Output which types/key an index has

Tags: sql, postgresql

I built this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    indexname 
FROM pg_indexes
WHERE schemaname = 'foo' AND 
      tablename = 'foo'
```

It returns me all indexes of a table. However, I would like the index names and the type of the indexes to be displayed, e.g. UNIQUE or PRIMARY.

Comment: you can use select *

Comment: But I don't need these columns. Isn't there a column that says if the index is UNIQUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from pg_index (not pg_indexes), like this:

```
SELECT it.relname, i.indisunique, i.indisprimary 
FROM pg_index i
INNER JOIN pg_class ct on i.indrelid = ct.oid
INNER JOIN pg_class it on i.indexrelid = it.oid
WHERE ct.relname = 'foo';
```

By way of explanation the indrelid column of pg_index contains the oid (in pg_class) of the table to which it belongs, whilst the indexrelid is the oid of the index itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to below. You can identify the key is unique or not from index definition (`indexdef`). Note that primary keys are also unique.

```
    SELECT 
        case when upper(indexdef) like '%UNIQUE%' then 'UNIQUE' else 'NOT_UNIQUE' end as case
    FROM pg_indexes 
    WHERE schemaname = 'foo' AND 
         tablename = 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I take the possibility of @Jonathan Willcock